# Liferay 6.1: Custom theme not inheriting from "Classic" theme

Tags: themes, liferay-6, inheritance

I've created a new theme using the Liferay Eclipse IDE and have modified `build.xml` to change the theme.parent to classic. Here is my complete `build.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE project>

<project name="deep-blue-theme" basedir="." default="deploy">
    <import file="../build-common-theme.xml" />

    <property name="theme.parent" value="classic" />
</project>
```

I'm not seeing any change in the theme. I still see the `_styled` layout being displayed. Is there anything else I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, changing the value of the "theme.parent" property in build.xml to "classic" should be enough.

But note that classic theme doesn't contain files such as custom.css which you could easily replace "to override default styles in one central location for easier upgrade and maintenance". If you want to save all styles in the classic theme, I see two possibilities:

**First approach**

1. Copy custom.css from classic theme to "docroot/_diffs/css" folder in your project.
2. Then add your styles to the end of that file.

**Second approach**

1. Create custom_deep_blue.css file in your project. Here you will add your styles.
2. Copy main.css from classic theme to "docroot/_diffs/css" folder.
3. Add the following @import to the end of the main.css file:

```
@import url(custom_deep_blue.css);
```